# Improve tagging by allowing users to note how familiar they are with the topic and askers how relevant a tag is to the question

Tags: feature-request, tags

I know HTML and CSS well, and know JS and some other stuff pretty well. (this wasn't meant to brag, just to give you my history)

I look though the HTML tag a lot, and there are a lot of questions I can't answer (i.e. JSON, jQuery, Google APIs, etc), I can't do ANYTHING with these questions, and they are useless to me. (this might not be necessary or wanted with people that have more experience/knowledge)

---

Here's my suggestion:

1. When you choose tags you like: when you select a tag, you should be able to select how much you know about that tag. (i.e. HTML, 100% knowledge, or HTML and a radio button that says "I know everything about HTML" or whatever.)
2. When someone posts a question: They type in tags that are relevant, after they do so a pop-up box opens up with the OPTION to choose how much of each tag is related do the question (percentage, check-box, etc).
3. People could find question they could answer easily and question askers would get then answered quicker.

Maybe there's some big flaw in this, but I just wanted to throw it out here and let you chew on it!

Comment: Considering how impossible it is to get people to use tags correctly in the first place, I don't think making tagging **more** difficult is a good idea. Also, someone may not realistically know how related a tag is to their question. They could have an idea that this is the only issue but it becomes clear later that they were wrong and it's not related much at all, in fact, the problem is utterly unrelated to that tag.

Comment: @Catija Good point.  But can't people edit the tags if they see one that isn't supposed to be there?  It seems like that would work pretty well!

Comment: Of course they can edit tags... but why make that process more difficult for editors, too? Would they also have to guess how related the tag is to the question? Most of my time here is on non-programming sites, so there's no benefit to a system like this. On cooking, if a question is about baking chocolate cakes, all the tags "baking", "chocolate" and "cakes" are valid and have equal importance. So this makes the tagging process very cumbersome.

Comment: How would this actually work. After declaring I know all about C++, do I see different questions than someone who has selected C++ as a favorite tag but says they're just learning? What drives that? Second, when people specify how relevant tags are to the question, what does that cause to happen? Do more or fewer people see the question? I see step 1 and 2 here, but it feels like "3: ???. 4: Profit!" at the moment.

Comment: You can add tags you don't know/care to "ignored tags" instead (look to the right side, click *edit* beside "Favorite Tags"). At least it will help you filter the questions.

Comment: You can already do this: remove the irrelevant tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When you choose tags you like: when you select a tag, you should be able to select how much you know about that tag.

After a while, one will know more and more about this tag they ask/answer questions about, so it will require frequent updating the "knowledge percent".

> They type in tags that are relevant, after they do so a pop-up box opens up with the OPTION to choose how much of each tag is related to the question

People often too lazy to correctly align the code in their questions, I doubt this will improve the quality of the questions/answers any better. Also, what about when someone edits the question and adding/removing the tags? By reading the question, one should know how much it is relevant to each of the tags.

> People could find question they could answer easily and question askers would get then answered quicker.

With what I wrote in the above sections. I think that it won't help the user asking, nor the user answering the question. It will add a bureaucracy layer and won't help you better finding questions you can answer unless you constantly update your knowledge about tags.

Comment: Thank you for your insight and opinions!  I realize now that it wouldn't work very well, would be hard to implement and even harder to get people to use it correctly.  Thanks again!